# AjaxFileUpload hide upload button and handle manually the upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I want to use [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx) control:

I am reviewing this, and the functionality I need is to hide the upload button, and save all buttons from another button click event.

Is it possible to do?

According to the properties they show, I dont see an option to hide the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source html, it seems that doing:

```
$('.ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton').hide();
```

Will do the trick of hiding the Upload button. The problem remains, though, as to whether an event is triggered when the user drops the first file or selects it via the Select button. I am sure there's one you can hook into to just call the above line of code (using jQuery on my example).

You can implement the same with pure Javascript.

Comment: just for the record this should say $('.ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton').hide(); notice the removal of the period and the addition of open quote.